# how can I suppress webdriver command window when I drivering Firefox?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url="http://www.baidu.com"
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('kw').send_keys(u"python")
browser.find_element_by_id('su').click()
```

when I run the above python code to drive Firefox, it always pops up a cmd window as below:

[image: window]

How can I suppress the cmd window? I am new in programming. Thanks a million!

I tried to drive chrome, and similar command box too. How can get rid of this annoying command window?